# Unable to build APP - Schema validation failed with the following errors: Data path ".builders['cordova-build']" should have required property 'class'

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, cordova, npm

> ng run app:ionic-cordova-build:production --platform=android
>   Schema validation failed with the following errors:
>     Data path ".builders['cordova-build']" should have required property 'class'.
>   [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ng.
>
> ng run app:ionic-cordova-build:production --platform=android exited
>   with exit code 1.
>
> Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve that issue by doing the below:

```
npm i @angular-devkit/architect@latest 
npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular@latest
npm i @angular-devkit/core@latest 
npm i @angular-devkit/schematics@latest
```

hope this will help you too.

cheers